# OpenVPN does not start on Debian 10

Tags: debian, virtualbox, openvpn, vpn

I have two virtual machines on my pc. One is OpenVPN server and the other is the client. I tried to go along
this tutorial: https://cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-10-set-up-openvpn-server-in-5-minutes/.

But my server did not start, and in `systemctl status openvpn@server` is:

```
openvpn@server.service - OpenVPN connection to server
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/openvpn@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-11-04 08:23:01 EST; 875ms ago
    Docs: man:openvpn(8)
          https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
          https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO
 Process: 17591 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-server --status /run/openvpn/server.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/server.conf --writepid /run/openvpn/server.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 17591 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Status: "Pre-connection initialization succesful"
```

In server.conf is:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 176.103.130.130"
push "dhcp-option DNS 176.103.130.131"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_dPoisKPsEF83iFyb.crt
key server_dPoisKPsEF83iFyb.key
auth SHA256
cipher AES-138-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3
```

Comment: Any clues in `journalctl -xe` and under the logs in `/var/log/openvpn/`?

Comment: in /var/log/openvpn is only empty file status.log and in journalctl -xe is only restart of service

Comment: Are you using subnet `10.8.0.x` anywhere else, for example on your LAN?

Comment: enp0s3 bridge network with another computer: 192.168.1.1, NAT enp0s8 10.0.3.15 and tun0 is 10.8.0.1

Comment: Please confirm the netmask for interface `enp0s8`